# Bluetooth tracking built into iOS?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, bluetooth, geolocation, gps

While there is a joint venture to produce an API by Google and Apple which allows truly anonymous contact tracing, is there an API for more generic device tracing, similar to how Tile and other Bluetooth based trackers work, but still anonymous - reporting locations of Bluetooth ‘tags’ only to the user (and not, of course, making available any information about the device which performed the detection.

I’m asking here because I can’t find a device/system which appears to be a suitable tracker (outside of the COVID API) which could be used for (eg) parents to track their children.

This question is specifically not about the ability for a service to provide information to users who have their app installed but wish to remain anonymous. It is about anonymous, community-based device reporting to allow Bluetooth ‘tags’ to be found.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - Apple’s API/SDK and framework for location aware Bluetooth technology is branded iBeacon.

- https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/

It is designed for your device to orient itself and take actions as soon as it comes within range of known devices. Look for this to get another jolt of attention when iOS 14 ships with App Clips and App Clip Codes.

- https://developer.apple.com/app-clips/

For tracking people, I would look first at the best dog tracker around (IMO).

- https://tryfi.com/

Mount that puppy on a bag, helmet or backpack until your children are old enough to merit their own smart device that uses [Apple Find My tracking](https://www.apple.com/icloud/find-my/) would be my advice for parents invested in the Apple ecosystem.